# $B$ a chain complex of free abelian groups and $C$ a chain complex such that $H_n(C)=0$. Then any chain map from $B$ to $C$ homotopic to the zero map

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $B$ be a chain complex of free abelian groups and let $C$ be a chain complex such that $H_n(C)=0$. Then any chain map from $B$ to $C$ is homotopic to the zero map.

So, $B$ is split and $C$ is exact. But I need maps (homomorphisms) $s_n:B_n\to C_{n+1}$ such that if $f$ is a chain map from $B$ to $C$ then $f=ds+sd$.

But I am unable to figure out these maps ${s_n}$. Could someone help me to figure out these maps or if a solution is not possible/too complicated using this method then is there any other way?

P.S. Kindly elaborate your statements.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your chain complexes are bounded, it is standard to construct all necessary maps by induction. Start with $s_0: B_0  \dashrightarrow C_1.$ For this we need $d \circ s_0 = f_0.$ Moreover, $C_1 \to C_0$ is surjective. Since $B_i$ are free, we can always solve equations like $d \circ s_0 = f_0$ by "cancelling" $d$: $s_0(b):= d^{-1}(f_0(b))$, where $d^{-1}$ takes any preimage, which exists due to surjectivity.

We can continue: for $s_1: B_1  \dashrightarrow C_2$ we'd need $d \circ s_1 = f_1 - s_0 \circ d.$ So we can repeat the same process as long as for every $b \in B_1$ there is $d^{-1}(f_1 - s_0 \circ d)(b).$ Now use exactness of $C$: this preimage exists as long as  $d(f_1 - s_0 \circ d)(b) = 0.$ Show this, using that $s_0$ already satisfies the chain homotopy equation.

And so on.

Comment: Which equation do you mean by the "chain homotopy equation"? Also, it isn't mentioned that either of the chain complexes are bounded.

Comment: @Anish Ray I mean the definition of chain homotopy.

Comment: But why did you assume that the chain complexes are bounded? It is not explicitly mentioned in the problem.

Comment: @Anish Ray I am pretty sure it is implied.

Comment: I believe the claim is false if the complexes are not assumed to be bounded below.

Comment: @John Palmieri I can observe that B would be bounded below but can you explain why C would be also bounded below?

Comment: I believe that there should be an example of a chain map $B \to C$ which is not chain homotopic to zero, where $C$ is the chain complex with $C_n = \mathbb{Z}/4$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and each boundary map is multiplication by 2. Maybe $B$ should consist of a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in dimensions 0 and 1, connected by the $\times 2$ map.